# Selenium Webdriver wait.until is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am starting to use Selenium Webdriver and I am encountering a problem with the **until** method from selenium.webdriver.support.wait. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


url = "http://shop.uclastore.com/courselistbuilder.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

departments = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('clDeptSelectBox'))
for department in departments.options:
    # select department
    departments.select_by_value(department.get_attribute('value'))


    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option")
    print elem
    print elem.get_attribute('value')

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 1.0)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option"))

    # time.sleep(1)

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option")
    print elem
    print elem.get_attribute('value')
    print
```

The problem is that when I print out the statements before and after I get:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x108a4af50>
0
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x108a4af90>
0

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x108a4afd0>
0
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x108a4af10>
0
```

where as when I comment out the **wait.until** code and uncomment the **time.sleep**, I get the following:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10378de90>
0
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10378de50>
84082

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10378df90>
0
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x103767110>
87846
```

So far, one possibility that I was thinking was that wait already found the **elem** which would imply that we should not get a zero value for the second print statement. However, that is not the case. So currently I do not know what is happening and need some help to figure it out.

Comment: This helped me....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819671/python-selenium-does-not-wait-until-page-is-loaded-after-a-click-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Your wait is waiting until `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option")` returns an element. But this is the wrong thing to test for.

The way that page is written, the `<select>` elements for "Campus" and "Term" are populated with `<option>` elements and have one `<option>` preselected. The `<select>` for "Department" is populated with `<option>` but has nothing preselected. The `<select>` elements for "Course" and "Section" are not populated.

The `<select>` element for "Course" becomes populated when a "Department" is chosen. **However**, before this `<select>` is populated, it *does* contain a placeholder `<option>` element that contains the text "Loading...". So whenever you look for `//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option`, you get a hit. In the version of your code with the `wait.until`, you find the placeholder `<option>` that exists before the JavaScript code on the page has had a chance to replace it with the real options. In the version of your code with `time.sleep(1)` you give the time to the JavaScript to do its work. However, note that **the `wait.until` call that you have does exactly what you asked it to do**.

#### Solution

You could wait until the value of the option is not 0:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option").get_attribute("value") != "0")
```

Note that `get_attribute` requires a round-trip between your script and the browser *in addition* to the `find_element...` round-trip. The following code does the same thing but uses only one round-trip:

```
def cond(driver):
    return driver.execute_script("""
    var option = document.querySelector("select#clCourseSelectBox>option");
    return option.value !== "0";
    """)

wait.until(cond)
```

The code above has been tested.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something this simple! Thanks for the helps.

Comment: You always help! SAMARITAN. You recovered my screwed head.